# Weird error in cider-jack-in

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I created a `clojure` project using `lein new`, started `GNU Emacs`, opened the file `core.clj` and when I tried to *jack-in* with `cider-jack-in` It blows off:

```
Making nrepl-create-client-buffer-function local to *nrepl-server clojure-noob* while let-bound!
Making nrepl-use-this-as-repl-buffer local to *nrepl-server clojure-noob* while let-bound!
Starting nREPL server via lein repl :headless...
nREPL server started on 37124
nREPL: Establishing direct connection to localhost:37124 ...
nREPL: Direct connection established
error in process filter: cider-repl-set-initial-ns: Symbol's value as variable is void: ns
error in process filter: Symbol's value as variable is void: ns
```

and then (obviously) nothing happens

My `core.clj` file is:

```
(ns clojure-noob.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "¡Soy una tetera pequeña y fuerte!"))
```

As you can see, nothing fancy or anything... (it runs with `lein run`)

My `.lein/profiles.clj` is pretty simple:

```
{:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.10.0-SNAPSHOT"]]}}
```

And my `cider` version is:

`CIDER 0.10.0snapshot (package: 20150830.328)`

as reported by `M-x cider-version`

I am new in `Clojure`, btw...

Could you help me?

Comment: Have you tried an older version of the cider-plugin? 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT sounds unstable. I'm using 0.6.0 because 0.7 didn't work right for me. Have you tried the most recent stable version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the latest version of `cider` (already fixed: http://bit.ly/1UfNgE9).

As for now, you can apply this change manually on your local `cider` installation or just wait for fix publishing.